# Определить соотношение сторон через @media

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как определить устройство с соотношением сторон дисплея `16/9` через `@media`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойства `aspect-ratio (min-aspect-ratio, max-aspect-ratio)`  – позволяют указать то, как ширина устройства должна относиться к высоте. В качестве значений допускается использовать только целые значения.

Для дисплеев с соотношением сторон 16/9 пример будет выглядеть так:

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) { 
    /* Стили CSS ... */ 
}
```